# Removing zeros in string at different places with QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, string, leading-zero

I'd like to take the values from the `"MAP_PAR_ID"` attribute and populate a new field without zeros (including leading zeros) in that field, e.g.:

| MAP_PAR_ID | New_Field |
| --- | --- |
| 0160011000 | 16-11 |

This works: `concat(substr("MAP_PAR_ID", 0, 3), '-', substr("MAP_PAR_ID", 5, 3))` but i need to detect also leading zeros and not include them.

I've tried numerous variations of `CASE ELSE` statements but can't even detect leading zeros. Feeble attempt below:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN substr("MAP_PAR_ID", 0, 1) = '0' THEN substr("MAP_PAR_ID", 1, 2)
    ELSE  substr("MAP_PAR_ID", 0, 3)

    WHEN substr("MAP_PAR_ID", 5, 1) = '0' THEN substr("MAP_PAR_ID", 6, 2)
    ELSE substr("MAP_PAR_ID", 5, 3)
END
```

Would the Python console make things a little easier?

Comment: I suppose you can have only one `ELSE` statement in `CASE WHEN` clause.

Comment: true, plus attributes aren't 0 indexed either.

Comment: how about: tostring(toint('0001')) does that return the string '1' ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [`regex_replace()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#regexp-replace) function for this:

```py
 regexp_replace('0160011000', '0+([1-9]+)0+([1-9]+)0+', '\\1-\\2')
 regexp_replace("MAP_PAR_ID", '0+([1-9]+)0+([1-9]+)0+', '\\1-\\2')
```

The regex is broken down like this:

- `0+` - Any number of zeros at the start
- `([1-9]+)` - Any number of values between 1 and 9. Capture into group 1
- `0+` - Any number of zeros in the middle
- `([1-9]+)` - Any number of values between 1 and 9. Capture into group 2
- `0+` - Any number of zeros at the end

The `regex_replace()` function is defined like this:

```py
regexp_replace(string,regex,after)
```

So in the after section we use `\\1-\\2` to add the values from group 1 and 2 into our new string.