# How to remove Commas from field values in multiple files?

Tags: qgis, arcmap, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I'm working in QGIS, presenting data in ArcMap, and Arc is having trouble with the attribute tables.

I have a "species" column which lists the species found in that area and have added commas "," in this field to separate species. Arc can't handle the commas so I would like to replace these in QGIS simply with a space.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I have tried `replace` and `regexp_replace` but I'm either doing this wrong or it is just not the way to do it...

I have a large amount of files to work with so an easy fix to this would be welcomed!

Comment: Have you tried to manipulate the table with other external program to edit the attribute table? (openoffice for example).

Answer (score 11):

You can use this command to replace all commas in the fields of your *Species* column with spaces:

```
regexp_replace( "Species", ',', ' ' )
```

In this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120609/remove-leading-zeros-with-qgis-field-calculator/120613#120613) answered by Nathan, the `regex_replace` function is described by :

```
regexp_replace(string,regex,after)
```

So in your case:

- **'string**' is your column (species)
- **'regex'** is the character you want changed (comma)
- **'after'** is what you want the character to be replaced with (leave empty for a space or add a space between the qutotation marks to create 2 spaces in the result)

---

**EDIT**:

I noticed I didn't answer the question completely as it asked how to remove commas in **multiple shapefiles**. Therefore, if all shapefiles are loaded into QGIS, you can use the following code to iterate through each layer and replace all commas with spaces for a specific field:

```
field = "Species"
formula = """ replace( "Species", ',', ' ' ) """

for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    idx = layer.fieldNameIndex( field )
    e = QgsExpression( formula )
    e.prepare( layer.pendingFields() )
    with edit(layer):
        for f in layer.getFeatures():
            f[idx] = e.evaluate(f)
            layer.updateFeature(f)
```

Comment: the simple replace function will work just as fine for this use case.

Comment: @underdark - Indeed it does!